# Webpack's UglifyJsPlugin not able to compile ES6 packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have this in my Webpack setup:

```
// webpack.prod.conf.js
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false,
    drop_console: shouldDropConsole
  },
  sourceMap: true
}),

// .babelrc
"presets": [
  ["stage-2"],
  ["es2015",  {"modules": false}]
],
```

When I do `npm run build` I get the following error:

> ERROR in static/js/vendor.8b608f0ab832a371f4a5.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected token: name (finish)
>   [./node_modules/pica/lib/mathlib.js:35,0][static/js/vendor.8b608f0ab832a371f4a5.js:38950,6]

So UglifyJS doesn't recognize the ES6 code there: `let`.

How to solve this? Is there any workaround? (I'm using Webpack 3.6.0).

Comment: What runtime/standard do you target?

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: UglifyJS3 support new syntax, but not UglifyJS2.

Comment: @tsh So how to update Webpack's Uglify? It's not listed in `package.json`. (And I think I'm using the lastest version of Webpack).

Comment: If you target ES5, then you need to transpile all ES2015+ code. Including selected directories from `node_modules`. You **DO NOT** need to update uglifyjs, you simply need to transpile your code and the libraries you use (unless they provide the ES5 code already).

Comment: @zerkms How do I tell Webpack or UglifyJS to do that?

Comment: In the very first place - `pica` library has `dist` directory with already transpiled files. So you can just use those. https://github.com/nodeca/pica/blob/master/README.md#install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (how to transpile ES6 to ES5 for node modules in a Webpack setup):

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [
     resolve('src'),
     resolve('test'),
     resolve('node_modules/pica'),
     resolve('node_modules/countries-list')
  ],
```

Comment: im getting `ReferenceError: resolve is not defined`.